# Multiple sensor circuits connecting to one counter and a 555 timer IC

Tags: digital-logic, 555, counter

I have to use a 555 timer in a context where I have multiple sensor circuits connecting to one counter circuit.
The idea is that the counter should indicate how many activated sensor circuits are there.
How do I even begin to approach that? I have no idea how to translate the number of activated inputs into a tangible value that I can display. And how to use a 555 in that context.

Also, Arduino/micro-controllers are NOT an option.

Any tips?

Comment: How often should the sensors' status be evaluated?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you described isn't what we'd call a *counter*, but a kind of decoder.

A counter increments its output each time an event occurs at its inputs, spread out over time. (Typically the "event" is a rising edge of the clock when an enable input is asserted)

It sounds like what you want is to have several inputs and to know how many of them are asserted at the same time. You can build this from a tree of *adder* circuits.

It's not clear why or how a 555 timer would be useful to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an odd system, but you might be able to do it.

You would need to be able to apply power to the sensors after the 555/counter circuit is active. Then, if you build in a delay for each sensor which would be different for each sensor, and activate a status line, you could diode/capacitor-couple the status lines to a single 555 which would produce a pulse for each transition. The 555 output would then drive the counter.

So, the sequence would be: 1) turn on the 555/counter, 2) apply power to the sensors, 3) count status pulses as the sensors become active, and 4) read the output of the counter after the appropriate delay.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solution and toolbox description is too vague to really give a concrete example, but if the sensors' sum current draw affect the charge time then you basically have a current to frequency converter, which when gated would give you a count of running sensors, given the appropriate scaling values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case, as I understand it, PROM/EPROM/EEPROM could solve your issue. You must send sensors to address lines and read from output.

The programmed content will be like this:

`Address         Data
0x00 (00000000) 0x00
0x01 (00000001) 0x01
0x02 (00000010) 0x01
0x03 (00000011) 0x02
0x04 (00000100) 0x01
0x05 (00000101) 0x02
0x06 (00000110) 0x02
0x07 (00000111) 0x03
0x08 (00001000) 0x01
and so on...`